# Using Handbrake to create a DVD

Tags: handbrake

I'm running Kubuntu 14.04.  I'm trying to use Handbrake to turn an MKV file into a playable DVD.  Supposedly Handbrake can do this -- but the only output format it seems to provide is, again, MKV.  I found a post suggesting that I disable the Ipod-friendly format, but I tried that and it made no difference.  Am I missing something?

Comment: You could try devede

Answer (score 1):

Handbrake converts videos into mp4 (H.264 etc), not into MPEG2 which is what you would need for "DVD" format.  You would need to convert the mkv file into MPEG2 video and then create the VOB file structure for the DVD (this is called "authoring" a DVD).

Here is a guide from 10 years ago describing the process - I guess the software is all too old to be in the current Ubuntu repos though:
https://www.linux.com/news/quick-guide-dvd-authoring

Comment: I discovered another program for this -- bombono.  It's free for Linux but not for Windows.  Bombono seems to work better than Devede, Handbrake,  or even k9copy.  I've had reasonable results with k9copy but it has some confusing peculiarities.  For instance, it offers an alternative (the default) of using k3b to write the DVD.  The trouble is that if  you then attempt to do that, you get a complaint about two processes attempting to write to the DVD at the same time.

Comment: Bombono offers it's source in a zip file on Github.  That seems a bit fishy to me.  Why not just offer the source the normal GitHub way?